# Print all lines from two similar files without duplicates

Tags: text-processing

I'm looking for a way to take two similar files (e.g. `~/.bashrc`) and print out all found lines, without duplicates. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want all unique lines then `cat file1 file2 | sort -u`, but I'm not sure that's what you really mean...

Comment: @StephenHarris works like I expected, thanks. Put it into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sort` command will sort files into order.  Add the `-u` flag and it will only produce unique lines of output.  So a file that shows as

```
abc
def
abc
```

will result in the output of

```
abc
def
```

This can be used for input from STDIN as well.

So we can `cat` both the source files and filter that through `sort -u`

```
cat file1 file2 | sort -u
```

This can be extended to any number of files and it will work the same way.

```
cat file1 file2 file3 ... file100 | sort -u
```